# Bootstrap with fixed width column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I've several columns

```
<div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 colA">
     Fixed width column for menu
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-7">
     Data with variable width
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-1 colC">
     Fixed width column for buttons
  </div>

</div>
```

I want the first and last column to have a fixed width.
So when in large screen sizes, the middle content will be adaptative but the side columns will always have the same width.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .colA { width: 200px; }
  .colC { width: 50px; }
}
```

And in small screen sizes the columns will all be fluid and in a normal bootstrap template.
So they reach the borders of the screen.

Simply by putting width in the column value doesn't work.

What can be a solution for this situation?
Is there another perspective I could try?

Comment: try giving !important. Or check what class properties overriding width:200px in 768 resolution

Comment: No, putting "!important" didn't work either

Comment: I created a plunker with your code. I see in lagerger screens it is taking 200 and 50px but in smaller screens(<768) it is taking 100% as of com-sm http://embed.plnkr.co/CmOttZnsfs43Hg5G2wnY/preview